# file-local-variables not evaluated on load

Tags: file-local-variables, orgtbl

Here is my example 
[mwe-1.tex](http://ix.io/2gs9)

local variable declaration from within this file is

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% mode: orgtbl
%%% End:
```

when I execute this command  in a shell:

```
emacs -q --eval '(load-library "org-table")' mwe-1.tex
```

The actual mode is latex but not orgtbl.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mode` for anything but the major mode is deprecated.  To enable minor modes, use `eval`:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% eval: (orgtbl-mode 1)
%%% End:
```

See [`(info "(emacs) Specifying File Variables")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).